# How to Generate UID From Object properties that can be used as ID for Entity in Custom Entity ID Generator?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, uid

So i have a problem, I need to know ID of an object that is going to be used in database, before i Persist it.

What I need to do is create custom generator :

```
public class CustomEntityIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
                                 Object object) throws HibernateException {


        if (object instanceof IWorkaround) {
            IWorkaround workaround = (IWorkaround) object;
            //TODO Generate UID from multiple Workaround properties.
            return 1l;
        } else {
            throw new HibernateException("Cannot generate custom ID for this Entity, Must be IWorkaround");
        }

    }

}
```

**Issue is : How do i safely and reliably Generate LONG ID from OBJECT PROPERTIES? I was thinking about concatenation of some of its properties into String, then do Hash of that string and somehow Put that HASH TO LONG, Problem is that HASH TO LONG  part, how do i do this reliably? What kind of algorithm fits here?**

Or is there a better way?

Note: Before someone asks, i cannot use +1 from sequence. Since This system can be used in parallel by multiple users. Cant rely on next number in sequence for id.

To better illustrate what im doing :

```
//Multiple people call
saveMe(objectToBePersisted){
  createDirectoriesAndProcessResources(idThatWillBeUsedInDB)// <-- Now I use ID
  otherStuff(objectToBePersisted);
  //Might have been declined and method ends
  saveToDB(objectToBePersisted)// <--now it gets ID
}
```

Comment: You can. That's the whole point of a database sequence: it can safely be used concurrently.

Comment: @JBNizet ?? I dont understand what you mean by YOU CAN, i obviously cannot, Imagine I have block of code, 2 people execute it and inside of it I ask ,What is going to be next id for this entity that i might not even save? 5, ok The other person also gets 5, what if now both will go thru and save, now whole process just went thru and behaved like i was going to save entity with id 5 for both users, for example i had resourcesto be saved and now i have resources for both entities in directory5. Even tho there are entities 5 and 6

Comment: No, the other people won't get 5, because the previous one has asked the next value, and the sequence thus has already incremented to 6. Every time you ask for the next value of a database sequance, it atomically inrements itself and returns the next value.

Comment: @JBNizet yes that is the case if i used normal sequence on .save(), bud i wont do that, i wont call SAVE() before i need this id  (I have to have ID before i call any persist method). Im not sure if you understand what i try to achieve. I dont touch any database bud I already need ID that is going to be used once i save entity. This class (the one in question code block) wont be even called at point where i will already need to use id.

Comment: Then why do you use a SequenceStyleGenerator? How do you expect the generate() to be called if you don't persist an entity? And how is it relevant if you persist the entity or not? If two concurrent users get the next value from a sequence, they will get a different value. You're free to do whatever you want with that value.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to use some generator custom one, Where i can define how ID is generated from Object information (SequenceStyleGenerator was in some random tutorial), The generator will call method that gets object and generates ID for it, same method will be called before generator so i know what ID its going to get once its saved. :D i just dont want to save FOR SAKE OF SAVING entity then, modify data, AND save again, i want to save it once,  bud before save i need to use ID that entity will have.

Comment: OK. So, forget your idea, and just get the next value from a sequence. then do whatever you want with that value.

Comment: @JBNizet That is what i do currently, bud i have to save before I for instance create Directories for my resources that use ID in path so i get that id, and then save again since im changing properties. And in case something goes wrong during my processing of resources I have to delete whatever is saved into db. Just too much overhead it feels like. ( In this case i dont use sequencer i just save so it gets id naturally - Default sequencer or whatever it is its used)

Comment: First, you shouldn't have to delete everything: rollbacking the transaction would automatically discare all the changes you made. Second, I think you're preoptimizing something that doesn't need to be. But anyway, I didn't tell you to save an entity. I told you to get the next value from a sequence. Using a simple SQL query. Then to do whatever you want with that value.

Comment: @mrkurtan ah this looks interesting, will look into!

Comment: @TomasBisciak I changed my comment to answer, if it helped please accept or comment it.

Comment: @mrkurtan I will try it once i will be able to get to my code :) Didnt had time yet, bud seems like it can be useful just dont know yet if its going to be solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a simplified base 64 or 62 with random sequence, you can calculate the collision chances for a given length and base. You don't have to generate it from the properties. You can play around: https://alex7kom.github.io/nano-nanoid-cc